# Async HTTP post gps cordinates

Tags: java, android

I want to send gps cordinates to a web service whenever the gps position on the phone gets updated.

Should i create a class that extends `AsyncTask` that sends the data to the webservice from the `onLocationChanged` event? Or do you guys suggest something else?

I started coding apps yesterday, so please tell me if im on the right track. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think this would be the right approach. Extend `AsyncTask` and in `doInBackground()` make the `POST/PUT` to your web server.

Another approach may be to use a `SocketConnection`, but this will still have to be operated in a background thread, and may add overhead, to thread `Socket` disconnection etc.

Just be sure to `unregister` your `BroadcastReceiver` in `onPause` and also handle your `AsyncTasks` to get cancelled when a new one will be executed, or the `Activity` stopped... etc, depending on your application needs.

If you would also like to send the location while your app is in background you should consider implementing a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) mechanism.

This has a lot of uses and is often overlooked by many Android developers.